# Is there a difference between '<?=' and '<?php'?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

I was looking at some sample code and I noticed that the code used

```
<?=
```

instead of

```
<?php
```

as opening tags, the closing tags were the same as usual, but I was just wondering if there is any different functionality between the two? The file extension of the sample code is also .phtml instead of .php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<?=` is not the same as `<?php`

`<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`

`<?` is the same as `<?php`

Comment: It's not the same, because it's not always available, and therefore not portable.

Comment: @Oli... It **IS** the same. He was asking for the difference or similarities. So to answer his question, they are the same, whether they are always available or not.

Comment: It is indeed the same. I agree though that improving the answer by saying that the short tags are not always enabled could be great. Except that, short echo tag rocks, and your answer too.

Answer (score 6):

`<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo ...`

It's used like so:

```
<?=$var1?>
```

instead of:

```
<?php echo $var1; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php:

> There are four different pairs of opening and closing tags which can
>   be used in PHP. Two of those, `<?php ?>` and `<script language="php">
>   </script>`, are always available. The other two are short tags and ASP
>   style tags, and can be turned on and off from the php.ini
>   configuration file. As such, while some people find short tags and ASP
>   style tags convenient, they are less portable, and generally not
>   recommended.
>
> ...
>
> Also note that if you are embedding PHP within XML or XHTML you will need to use the `<?php ?>` tags to remain compliant with standards.

So in summary, use `<?php ?>`.

Comment: `<?=` **is** different than `<?php`

Comment: I could see from the article you pointed out that it is a shortcut to echo whatever is in the tags, thanks!

Comment: @Oli don't you see my comment?

Comment: @Matthieu: I did.  But how does that relate to my answer?

Comment: @Oli, quoting the OP: "I was just wondering if there is any different functionality between the two?"... And you say "use `<?php ?>`" whereas if the OP would replace the tags in his code, it wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: @Matthieu: Indeed.  But I'd count "not always available" as a pretty big difference in functionality!  So that's what my answer is about.

Comment: @Oli: edited comment while you answered, sorry about that, see my other point too

Answer (score 0):

`<?=` prints the result of the PHP. It's roughly equivalent to `<?php echo ...`

`<?php` of course just starts the code block.

Comment: It is equivalent, not roughly equivalent ;)

Answer (score 0):

`<?=` is shorthand for `<? echo`

so you could write

```
Hello, <?= $name ?>.
```

instead of

```
Hello, <? echo $name ?>.
```